# Angular2 set meta title and description

Tags: angular

I created an angular2 website and while i build it i setup the meta title and description along the lines of what this tutorial did http://blog.devcross.net/2016/03/20/angular-2-seo/. This seemed to work and the title in the browser actual updated ok. The problem is that when i do a view source of the site it still only shows me the html source which resides in the main index.html file not the updated values.

When i check the source in the console with firebug lite it shows me updated meta titles and the description.

What am i doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see the page's source code, no javascript is executed, so you will not be able to see the changes aplied by Angular. This is normal. You aren't doing anything wrong based on that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I see. But when the pages will get indexed by google will they also have that meta title or will those have the updated ones?

Comment: Google looks to your page after executing any code, including JavaScript. So, it will read the correct title and any other meta tags.
:-)

Comment: You can always ensure this by using the Google Webmaster Tools.

Answer (score 4):

Since [Angular4-beta.0](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) there is the `Meta` service

```
constructor(private meta:Meta) {
  meta.addTag({ name: 'description', content: 'your description' })
}
```

For more details see https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/12322/files#diff-7979e98d95c45d21e56cf2602244f220R36