# Angular 2: How to add and update the meta tags dynamically from a component (like title service)

Tags: angular

I am very new to Angular 2. I need to set up the meta tags like og: description and all from a component. I have no idea how to dynamically update the meta tags, also add new tags to the index.html from a particular component.

Please help.

PS: I read about title service, but that is to update the title only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119398/how-can-i-update-meta-tags-in-angularjs

Comment: My question is related to the angular 2 only. I wanted to have some idea about how this thing can be done in angular 2.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I should have used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536237/angular2-set-meta-title-and-description/42245535#42245535

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [Angular4-beta.0](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) a `Meta` service was added that allows you to add/remove meta tags

```ts
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private meta:Meta) {
  meta.addTag(...)
}
```

For more details see

- https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta
- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/12322/files#diff-7979e98d95c45d21e56cf2602244f220R36

Comment: I am able to set the tags in index.html with Meta service,but when I share the url in facebook or social media ,its not showing the meta tags. If i directly put the meta tags in index.html its showing tags. so how can i show the dynamic tags in social media?

Comment: Probably only by adding them statically. I don't know how and when Facebook reads the tags, but it looks like it does before Angular adds them.

Comment: thanks for reply. I heard about server side rendering, my project is using angular with spring rest API. so is there any way to use that for meta tags?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about server-side rendering. I would expect it to work better for your use case though.

Comment: @NazirAhmed There shouldn't be a need to make it `public`

Comment: Hi Gunter, can you help me in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52781566/angular-meta-service-not-adding-and-updating-dynamic-tag-values

Answer (score 10):

First import Meta service in your component

```
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Put it in the constructor

```
constructor(private Meta:Meta){}
```

Use the service:

```
this.Meta.addTag({ name: 'yourmetaname', content: 'yourmetacontent' });
```

you can look for more information in oficial DOCS:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/Meta-class.html

Comment: Hi Shanti, can you help me in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52781566/angular-meta-service-not-adding-and-updating-dynamic-tag-values

Answer (score 7):

In Angular 4 you can easily update your web page title and meta tag information.

1. Import the predefined Meta Service in your component.

   import { Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
2. Inject the Service in Constructor.

```js
constructor(private title: Title, private meta: Meta) {}
```

3. Add title and meta tag in ngOnInit() using setTitle and updateTag

```js
 ngOnInit(){    
        this.title.setTitle('Angular Overview');    
        this.meta.updateTag({ name:'author',content:'angulartpoint.com'});    
        this.meta.updateTag({name:'keyword',content:'angular overview, features'});    
        this.meta.updateTag({name:'description',content:'It contains overview of angular application'});    
    }
```

4. Check the head tag in the browser.

[image]

Comment: Hi Sachin, can you help me in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52781566/angular-meta-service-not-adding-and-updating-dynamic-tag-values